# library not found in tesseract?

Tags: ios4, ocr, tesseract

I downloaded tesseract demo code of "rcarlsen-Pocket-OCR-9912da9" from https://github.com/rcarlsen/Pocket-OCR/downloads
Now i am facing problems with libraries used in it.Can anyone tell how can i solve this?or from where i can get it?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

#import "ZoomableImage.h"

// conditionally import or forward declare to contain objective-c++ code to here.
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import "baseapi.h"
using namespace tesseract;
#else
@class TessBaseAPI;
#endif

@interface OCRDisplayViewController : UIViewController
<UIActionSheetDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {
TessBaseAPI *tess;
UIImage *imageForOCR;
NSString *outputString;

UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;

IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cameraButton;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *actionButton;

IBOutlet ZoomableImage    *thumbImageView;
IBOutlet UILabel        *statusLabel;
IBOutlet UITextView *outputView;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *outputString;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UITextView *outputView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *cameraButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *actionButton;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet ZoomableImage *thumbImageView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *statusLabel;

@end
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to larger screenshot, current one is too small to read.

Comment: right click on it and select open image in new tab :)

Answer (score -2):

I think the misstake in line (because it's cpp)

```
#import "baseapi.h"
```

try this and type semicollons manually!!!

```
#include "baseapi.h"
```

the file should be in red color.